# How long does a sentry gun last in Spec Ops: Survival?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've been experimenting with Survival mode in Modern Warfare 3 Spec Ops, but I haven't quite unlocked everything yet.  One thing that seems like it should be super useful is the sentry gun.  There also appears to be a sentry grenade turret as well.

How long do these last?  Do they eventually time out, or do they die due to enemies shooting them?  Do the enemies target sentry guns?  Will they path differently if one is in place?

Comment: The sentry gun pretty well sucks. They are dumb as hell and slow. I have many times had 1 guy with an mp5 kill my sentries before I could go 100ft to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can make out they last indefinitly until destroyed. I have had sentry guns last up to 30 rounds before they were taken out.

The enemies WILL target your sentries and this also changes their pathing and stradegy. 
Ive had enemies ignore myself and\or my partner and beeline for my guns attempting to knife them. (such an attack IS an instant kill on your guns and will likely be the way the enemey takes them down)

Dogs, it should be interesting to note, dont seem to properly register your sentries, and will often get 'stuck' on them, running in place until they are shot dead, or you move and the AI for the dog changes its course to run at you.

I barely use Grenade Launcher Sentries but the few times I have used them they seemed somewhat decent, if albiet extremly slow to shoot.

Normal Sentry Guns however, are golden. Brian has his opinion and he is entitled to that, but I have found that S.Guns, WITH PROPER PLACEMENT AND SUPPORT, are one of the strongest support equipments available and will more than pay for themselves in short order.

Note: IT IS EXTREMELY IMPORTANT THAT YOU EXPERIMENT WITH WHERE YOU PLACE THEM. Improper sentry placement\support will make them nothing more than an expensive waste of time.  This is doubly so for juggernauts who tend to go through Sentries like a hot knife through butter. You might want to lead the juggs AWAY from your guns if possible, but the choice is yours of course.

Edit-Afterthought: I should specify that the guns work best when you support them. Left by themselves the guns will inevitably get overrun and destroyed, but when you work together with them is when they truly shine.

Comment: I've found I like to place them in a kind of secure area near me, sometimes in a little alcove in an area where I'm closer to the bad guys than it is.  When it starts to fire, I know someone's flanking, and I can generally switch to focusing on that direction.  I think Delta Team is almost a better thing to have though, especially with Juggernauts.

Comment: @agent- well you can have both sentries and Delta so why not? and in certain stages, with the proper placement, you can have both sentries putting insanse rounds into juggs for quite some time as they slowly walk toward you.

Comment: I've found using a Grenade Launcher and a Normal one in tandem works well - one to knock many of them over (and damage them all a bit) and one to sweep them all up while they lie down.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have two normal sentries and riot squad. They will go through several waves without me doing anything, they even take out the jugs for me.

Answer (score 0):

They last until destroyed (and generally outlast the Delta Squad or Riot Shield Squads by many, many waves). Enemies can shoot, knife, or use explosives to destroy them.

Working on ranking up to 50 (rank 45 now), but found that 2 sentry grenade launchers can actually take out a juggernaut for me on occasion. When teaming up with my usual partner, we each get a sentry grenade launcher and a riot shield squad for best effect.

I do still really like the regular sentry gun, though. Esp since its quicker to fire and does a fair amount of damage on its own.

Answer (score 0):

On resistance get two grenade sentry's and put the them on the tables on the balcony with only one stairway up they last 5-7 rounds but they make 2k more than they cost so you can buy a riot squad and they last between 4-10 rounds depending on how well you help them or if you lay at the top of the stairs they stand on them and cover the little arc walkway